# Dynamic Plot with AndroidPlot update example

Tags: androidplot

Hi I' am triing to undertsad how androidplot works and I was triing to create a dynamic plot but the example that I found in the official web site is not update and it doesn't work with the version 0.6, do you know where I can find an update example??? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most of the tutorials are derived from the source code of the DemoApp which is always kept up to date for the latest release.  [Here's the full source](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/397fac6a3541b4020a716e958a9c0b42bd2450fd/Examples/DemoApp/src/com/androidplot/demos/DynamicXYPlotActivity.java?at=master) of the DynamicXYPlotActivity (upon which the tutorial is based) updated for 0.6.2.